# Query returning just one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm running this MySQL query in PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM settings
```

This is the settings table:

```
id ------- name ------- value
_____________________________
 1 --------- one --------- 1  
 2 --------- two --------- 2
```

For some reason, when I run my query I'm only given the first result (even when running a `foreach` loop).
I've taken a look around and can see that a workaround is to run a `while` loop. This to me looks a bit counter-active.

My question is, why is this occurring, and how can I *fix* it to run as a standard `foreach` loop?

**Edit**
The PHP code:

```
$query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM settings");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: We should imagine your php code, right?

Comment: Because your using old mysql (mysql_fetch_array) and not mysqli or pdo. Fix: use mysqli/pdo

Comment: @u_mulder I didn't expect it to be difficult to work out how to write a simple PHP/MySQL query with the MySQL I posted above.

Comment: @chresse A [result set from PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) does implement `Traversable`, so does in fact allow to `foreach` over the queried data. (Unlike the dated `mysql_` approach, which only permits the `while` loop.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to walk through you resultset with a loop:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
$query = "SELECT * FROM settings";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
echo "<pre>"; 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

or if you want to use `PDO` (i.e. use a `foreach`):

```
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=databasename;host=localhost", "username", "password" );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM settings";

    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: This will not work. mysqli_query($connection, $query). Also you are using mysql_fetch_assoc

Comment: check the manual for http://us3.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.query.php for mysqli_query syntax

Comment: @fortune: sry. i forgot. I fixed it.

Comment: still you are using mysql_fetch_assoc with mysqli*.